# vuejs button not clickable when in v-if

Tags: vue.js, button

I have the following problem:
when putting a button in conditionnal rendering with v-if, it is not 'clickable' anymore.

```html
    <div class="DoubleBtn" v-for="group in groups" :key="group.role">
                  <button v-if="group.role === 'student'"
                    type="button"
                    @click="removePresence()"
                    class="float-right btn btn-danger" >
                 
                    Out
                  </button>
                  <button v-if="group.role === 'student'"
                    type="button"
                    @click="updateRooms()"
                    class="float-right btn btn-success" >
                  
                    In
                  </button>
                </div>
```

thank your for reading!

Comment: I think you should check if those 2 @click functions work as intended

Comment: Not sure if it's somehow related, but use `updateRooms` rather than `updateRooms()`. The latter will self invoke itself on render. The first will be called on a `click` event. So here, you probably want to have the regular non-() one.

Comment: `updateRooms()` is actually fine in vue.js

Comment: yes both work fine. The one without the brackets makes the most sense though. Also `v-if` should not affect any events, it only decides whether the element is rendered or not.

Comment: now that I think of it, there is are situations to use `@click="updateRooms(someparam)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you having two `if statements` that have the same condition? Can try to put both of the buttons in a single `if block` something like this:

```
<div v-if="group.role === 'student'">

<button 
                    type="button"
                    @click="removePresence()"
                    class="float-right btn btn-danger" >
                 
                    Out
                  </button>
                  <button 
                    type="button"
                    @click="updateRooms()"
                    class="float-right btn btn-success" >
                  
                    In
                  </button>


</div>
```